# CMake cannot find source file, even though it is in the correct location

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am adding some mirroring effects to easypaint. While I was building the project, I came across an issue. When I run generate in CMake (yes I know QMake would be better for this, but we have to use CMake), it keeps giving me an error in the CMakeLIsts.txt file saying it can't find one of my mirror cpp files. I have all my code inserted into the appropriate files and headers in the project, and I have added the headers and cpp files to the appropriate spots in the CMake Lists file.

Error in CMake:
""""
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:129 (add_executable):
Cannot find source file:
  sources/effect/mirrorrighteffect.cpp

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx

I double checked that all files are in the proper directories, so I don't know what the issue is.

```
#------- headers --------
set (HEADERS
sources/mainwindow.h
sources/easypaintenums.h
sources/imagearea.h
sources/datasingleton.h
sources/additionaltools.h
sources/effects/abstracteffect.h
sources/effects/negativeeffect.h
sources/effects/grayeffect.h
sources/effects/binarizationeffect.h
sources/effects/customeffect.h
sources/effects/effectwithsettings.h
sources/effects/gammaeffect.h
sources/effects/mirrorrighteffect.h   <<<-----------My file
sources/effects/mirrordowneffect.h    <<<-----------My file
sources/effects/gaussianblureffect.h
sources/effects/sharpeneffect.h
sources/undocommand.h
sources/widgets/toolbar.h
sources/widgets/colorchooser.h
sources/widgets/palettebar.h
sources/widgets/palettebutton.h
sources/widgets/shortcutedit.h
sources/widgets/abstracteffectsettings.h
sources/widgets/customfiltersettings.h
sources/widgets/sharpenfiltersettings.h
sources/widgets/gaussianblurfiltersettings.h
sources/widgets/imagepreview.h
sources/dialogs/resizedialog.h
sources/dialogs/settingsdialog.h
sources/dialogs/textdialog.h
sources/dialogs/effectsettingsdialog.h
sources/instruments/abstractinstrument.h
sources/instruments/abstractselection.h
sources/instruments/selectioninstrument.h
sources/instruments/pencilinstrument.h
sources/instruments/lineinstrument.h
sources/instruments/eraserinstrument.h
sources/instruments/rectangleinstrument.h
sources/instruments/ellipseinstrument.h
sources/instruments/fillinstrument.h
sources/instruments/sprayinstrument.h
sources/instruments/magnifierinstrument.h
sources/instruments/colorpickerinstrument.h
sources/instruments/curvelineinstrument.h
sources/instruments/textinstrument.h)

#------- sources --------
set (SOURCES
sources/main.cpp
sources/mainwindow.cpp
sources/imagearea.cpp
sources/datasingleton.cpp
sources/additionaltools.cpp
sources/effects/abstracteffect.cpp
sources/effects/negativeeffect.cpp
sources/effects/grayeffect.cpp
sources/effects/binarizationeffect.cpp
sources/effects/effectwithsettings.cpp
sources/effects/gammaeffect.cpp
sources/effect/mirrorrighteffect.cpp   <<<-----------My file
sources/effect/mirrordowneffect.cpp    <<<-----------My file
sources/undocommand.cpp
sources/widgets/toolbar.cpp
sources/widgets/colorchooser.cpp
sources/widgets/palettebar.cpp
sources/widgets/palettebutton.cpp
sources/widgets/shortcutedit.cpp
sources/widgets/customfiltersettings.cpp
sources/widgets/sharpenfiltersettings.cpp
sources/widgets/gaussianblurfiltersettings.cpp
sources/widgets/imagepreview.cpp
sources/dialogs/resizedialog.cpp
sources/dialogs/settingsdialog.cpp
sources/dialogs/textdialog.cpp
sources/dialogs/effectsettingsdialog.cpp
sources/instruments/abstractinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/abstractselection.cpp
sources/instruments/selectioninstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/pencilinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/lineinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/eraserinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/rectangleinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/ellipseinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/fillinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/sprayinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/magnifierinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/colorpickerinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/curvelineinstrument.cpp
sources/instruments/textinstrument.cpp)
```

Comment: `sources/effects/mirrorrighteffect.h` and `sources/effect/mirrorrighteffect.cpp` is the folder `sources/effects` or `sources/effect`? I believe you have a typo.

Comment: oh, wow. I can't believe I missed that. I guess it just takes another set of eyes sometimes. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: OT: I usually create a CMakeLists.txt in each subfolder and append to the source variables or just make a static library for each subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a typo in `sources/———>>>effect<<<——-/mirrorrighteffect.cpp`.

I believe it must be  `sources/effects/mirrorrighteffect.cpp` instead.